# Concept of Object, class and member function

Tags: class, object, member-functions

So far this is what I understand objects are, I need feedback to know if I'm correct.

A *class* is made up of *member functions*.  A *class* also defines types like *int* does.
An *object* is defined by that *class* and then the *object* calls the *member functions* within that *class* (only in the *class* it was defined by).

Need to know if I'm missing anything or if I'm wrong about something. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class is made up of member functions.
Not necessarily, classes can contain data members too.

A class also defines types like int does.
True

Then the object calls the member functions within that class
Once, you go through the concepts of inheritance, you will understand that, an object can call methods of its base classes